# Why sequelize.sync() always return empty models?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have 2 express.js applications and run sequelize.sync(), but in my first app it generate the tables, and the others not generate the tables, i wonder why, because the script is identic.

database.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('student-affairs', 'root', '', {
    dialect: 'mysql',
    host: 'localhost',
    operatorsAliases: false,
});

module.exports = sequelize;
```

organization.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = require('../configs/database');

const Organization = sequelize.define('organization', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    logo: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    createdBy: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    updatedBy: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    }
});

module.exports = Organization;
```

app.js

```
// Database
const sequelize = require('./configs/database');

sequelize
  .sync()
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result);
    app.listen(3001);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

But after i log it, it always return the models empty like this

models: {},
modelManager: ModelManager { models: [], sequelize: [Circular] },

it doesn't have the models. anyone can explain why? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just realize that i am not call the organization model in app.js, once i define it in app.js and it fix the problem.

I think it's a basic mistake. Now i understand how it works.

```
// Models
const Organization = require('./models/organization');

sequelize
    .sync()
    .then(result => {
        app.listen(3000);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: Create an index file inside models folder with the following code - https://pastebin.com/3N8Bb8fA and you would not be needing to manually require models in the file. Call the above index file once where your server is starting

Comment: @RohitDalal i have tried with the code but my model still empty , , , where is similar to from init project sequalize command .